# Assigning an array to another: Array Covariance

Tags: vb.net

I have two arrays and both of them have reference type elements in them. The rule for assigning one array to another in such a case, as per MSDN documentation ([MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-assign-one-array-to-another-array)) is as follows:

> If both arrays have reference type elements, the source element type
> must derive from the destination element type. When this is the case,
> the two arrays have the same inheritance relationship as their
> elements.

I wrote the following code to understand the above statement. In the code the arrays `grade_one`, `grade_two` has reference type elements of the type `Student`(base class) and `highSchoolStudent` (derived class) respectively. Also, I have done two kinds of assignment: `grade_one = grade_two` and the reverse i.e. `grade_two = grade_one`. Because of the statement quoted above, I was expecting that in one of the assignments I shall be getting an error. That's not the case - both works. Clearly I am not understanding the statement so can anyone please explain what the above statement means? Code i wrote given below:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim grade_one(1) As Student
        grade_one(0) = New Student("Alex", 15)
        grade_one(1) = New Student("Roger", 13)

        Dim grade_two(1) As highSchoolStudent
        grade_two(0) = New highSchoolStudent("Tim", 19, "Physics")
        grade_two(1) = New highSchoolStudent("Tom", 18, "Biology")

        grade_one = grade_two
        grade_two = grade_one
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module


Class Student
    Property name As String
    Property age As Integer
    Sub New(ByVal n As String, ByVal a As Integer)
        name = n
        age = a
    End Sub
End Class

Class highSchoolStudent
    Inherits Student
    Property subject As String
    Sub New(ByVal n As String, ByVal a As Integer, ByVal s As String)
        MyBase.New(n, a)
        subject = s
    End Sub
    
End Class
```

Comment: Delete `grade_one = grade_two` to get the error you're looking for.

Comment: What do you think this line does: `grade_one = grade_two`? It gets the object assigned to `grade_two` and assigns it to `grade_one`, thus discarding the object that was previously assigned. Both variables now refer to the same object. With that in mind, wht do you think this line does: `grade_two = grade_one`? If both variables refer to the same object, it effectively does nothing.

Comment: @jmcilhinney agree...it does nothing. I should have noticed this.

Comment: @HansPassant hi. Did it. Got an error when tried to compile, I guess that's expected. Just to clarify, that when we say Array Covariance, we mean that an array of a more derived type can be implicitly converted to an array of a less derived type. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: No, variance is checked at runtime, not compile-time.  So you must actually run the program to see the InvalidCastException.  Controversial design decision, rumored to be made because Java works this way.  Clearly you want to always avoid it.

Comment: @HansPassant Asking a very basic question to be sure that I am clear about the ideas of "Compile" and "Run". I am getting the InvalidCast error when I press the green triangular button in the second row from top in the Visual Studio IDE. I believe that action first 'compiles' and then 'runs' the application. And it is while 'running' that the error is displayed. However when I choose "Build Solution" under the BUILD tab I am not getting any error -- i believe this is the compilation step only. Am I understanding this correctly now?